# Binding onclick event to sum two numbers doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I’m making a simple sum function. It’s not working properly. What is wrong?

```js
let B = document.getElementById('bu');
let input1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('qq').innerHTML);
let input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('qw').innerHTML);

B.onclick = (a, b) => {
  if (a + b === 100 || a === 100 || b === 100) {
    alert('you did it');
  } else {
    alert('try again');
  }
}
B.onclick(input1, input2);
```

```html
<div class="but">
  <input type="text" id="qq">
  <input type="text" id="qw">
  <button id="bu"> check</button>
</div>
```

When I put `100` in `input1` or `input2` or `input1 + input2 === 100`, I want to alert “you did it”, otherwise “try again”.

Comment: Put the `let input1 = ...` and `let input2 = ...` lines inside the `onclick` callback. You want to parse these when the button is clicked, not when you load the page. Also remove the last line `B.onclick(input1, input2);`

Comment: _`B.onclick = (a,b) => {` … `}` … `B.onclick(input1, input2);`_ — that’s not how you bind click events at all. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

To read a value from input (type=text) , use the value property: [MDN input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

A better way to add a click listener: [MDN click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

[Demo code (coepen)](https://codepen.io/krocon/pen/gOPpjrK)

```
let B = document.getElementById('bu');
const qq = document.getElementById('qq');
const qw = document.getElementById('qw')

B.onclick = () => {
    let a = parseInt(qq.value, 10);
    let b = parseInt(qw.value, 10);

    if (a + b === 100) {
        alert('you did it');
    } else{
        alert('try again');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the radix. It's not important, because 10 is the default. But if you use a tool like sonarqube, you will get a hint to set the radix explicitly.  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `a === 100` and the `b === 100` are not needed in the condition, is enough with `a + b === 100`

In the other hand, you should do something like this, because `a` and `b` are not injected in the event function of the onclick button action. So, the solution is something like this:

```
let B = document.getElementById('bu');
B.onclick = () => {
  let a = parseInt(document.getElementById('qq').value) || 0;
  let b = parseInt(document.getElementById('qw').value) || 0;
  if (a + b === 100) {
    alert('you did it');
  } else {
    alert('try again');
  }
};
```

Comment: I use the `innerHTML` from your base code, but it should be `value` instead, so it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Not .innerHTML, they are input boxes so you should use .value. As others have said, if you define the set values of each field at runtime, you cannot recieve changes made later. The other solutions will also work. I also recommend using parseFloat as opposed to parseInt for calculations so you can verify decimal values (e.g. 99.1 + 0.9 = 100).

Remember, if you do define a or b as "const qq = document.getElementById('qq'); const qw = document.getElementById('qw');", this needs to be done after the page has loaded (onload).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
     calculate = (a,b) => {
       a = parseFloat(a) || 0;
       b = parseFloat(b) || 0;
         alert(a + b === 100 ? 'you did it' : 'try again');
       }
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="but">
      <input type="text" id="qq" />
      <input type="text" id="qw" />
      <input type="submit" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('qq').value,document.getElementById('qw').value)" value="Calculate" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will work fine. But iin this case the calculate function will be global. A better way is to add the onlick via javascript.

Comment: Provided it is set after page/window has loaded so the element exists before defining (window.onload)

Comment: Sure. But what I want tos say:  If one uses an onlick attribute,the funcktion must be 'global' and  it's not possible to encapsulate the code via IIFE:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 0):

Several remarks:

- if you put "let", the "onclick" function won't be able to access the variable. Take a look at the differences between "let", "var", "const", etc.
- if you want an input to handle numbers, put "type='number'"
- writing "+" before a varaible is shorter than "parseInt"
- if you initialize your variable like this: input1 = document.getElementById('qq').value, "input1" will stay the same. Take a look at differences between types and references
- when you write "B.onclick = (a, b) => {", it means you're calling the function triggered by the click event with the click event as "a", and nothing as "b". In your case it's better to use an anonymous function.

```js
let B = document.getElementById('bu');
var input1 = document.getElementById('qq');
var input2 = document.getElementById('qw');

B.onclick = () => {
  if (+input1.value + (+input2.value) === 100 || +input1.value === 100 || +input2.value === 100) {
    alert('you did it');
  } else {
    alert('try again');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="but">
  <input type="number" id="qq" />
  <input type="number" id="qw" />
  <button id="bu"> check</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, I've modified your code a little bit.

```js
// select elements
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const input1 = document.getElementById('qq');
const input2 = document.getElementById('qw');

// calc fn
const calc = (a, b) => {
    if ((a + b === 100) || (a === 100) || (b === 100)) alert('you did it');
    else alert('try again');
}

// click event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => calc(+input1.value, +input2.value));
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="number" id="qq">
    <input type="number" id="qw">
    <button type="button" id="btn">check</button>
</div>
```